# What is the point of Jacob's Ladder?

Tags: redemption-tcg

I have the artifact Jacob's Ladder (from the Patriarchs expansion). For the life of me I can't figure out its use or why I'd want to include it in a deck.

The text on the card reads:

> "Holder may choose which Lost Soul is to be rescued during Holder's
>   rescue attempt. Holder must have access and may only rescue that Lost
>   Soul."

First, this text makes it appear that this *only* affects the holder (ie, owner) of the card. This ability looks like it restricts which Lost Soul you can attempt to rescue. If anything, this is a restriction placed on you the player and not on your opponent. I'm not sure why I'd want to do this.

Second, that style of restriction (ie, player's choice) is always used for Type II deck tournaments (as opposed to Type I deck tournaments, where that restriction apparently doesn't exist).

So...can anyone explain to me the point of this card? If I'm building a Type II deck, I already have to play by those rules (good idea to follow tournament rules). And if I'm building a Type I deck, why would I want to place a restriction on myself?  Is there something I'm not understanding? Is there a ruling on this card by which it is played differently? Does anyone out there use this card?

Comment: Seems like the "Holder *may* choose, just be the key.  As if there were multiple Lost Souls, and you get to choose one, and only one to rescue.  Perhaps this is for situations where there are multiple lost souls and you cannot choose which Lost Soul to rescue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Redemption rulebook:  In the detailed Hero Wins section:  " your opponent
must select and surrender to you one available Lost Soul from his Land of Bondage. "
[(Redemption Rules)](http://www.cactusgamedesign.com/downloads/rules_4th_edition_final.pdf)

Since it's always your opponents choice, this card is valuable in situations where the Lost Soul you rescue matters.   It allows the Hero to choose instead of the Evil opponent.

Comment: I thought you always had to state which Lost Soul you were engaging in battle for. Reason being someone could pull a Son of God on you and rescue it and now you cannot rescue the Soul you declared and may have to fight for nothing.

Comment: The rules didn't seems to suggest that you had to declare who you were righting for, and it seemed pretty clear that the opponent chooses from the pool of available lost souls to give to you.  Perhaps that was an update in the rules?  It seemed like the original redemption box only came with lost souls that have no effects on them so it didn't matter very much which one you got.  Perhaps I'm wrong.  I've never played the game,  I've only read the rules.